# Noun tags: should we prefer singular form over plural form?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we use "buffer" or "buffers", "file" or "files", ...?

EDIT: I realized that I included my opinion into the "question", sorry for that.  I will instead answer my own question with my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

For uncountable nouns, the singular has to be used.

For countable nouns, let's ask [English Stack Exchange](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags): 17 in favor of the plural, a net score of 1 for the singular. That's pretty much a consensus in favor of the plural.

Tag names are usually what you use to complete the sentence “this question is about ____”. Thus [buffers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffers), [files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files), etc.

There's one reason to prefer an arbitrary choice sometimes: for the sake of possible migrations, it's best to align with existing sites ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags), etc.) when applicable.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion tags should be in singular form unless there is a really good reason to use the plural form.  I would much prefer "buffer" over "buffers", "file" over "files" etc.  Usually when a question applies to *foobars* it also applies to a single *foobar*.

Of course there are always exceptions to a rule: for instance, when tagging questions related to multiple modes then the plural form "multiple-modes" comes naturally and should be preferred.